# Seeking powermeter data

Tags: bike-computer, power

I am developing a small tool that allows to pick a day for a long cycle trip. The idea is to use weather forecasts to compute how bad/good the wind along the route in the following days is. You can have a look and read further details in [the project page](https://github.com/esovetkin/biketour).

One of the requirements for the model accuracy are good estimates of the real physical parameters used in the model. This parameters are personal and depend on the rider/cycle. Therefore, the program should have a feature to estimate those parameters, provided some powermeter data. Unfortunately, I don't have a powermeter, so I cannot collect the data myself and play around with the way those parameters are estimated.

Therefore, I am reaching out for people who have a powermeter and willing to help me to get this data examples. The data I need should ideally contain the following entries: timestamp, latitude, longitude, elevation, power. The entries are needed to be collected along a cycle trip (or several).

Comment: Quite interesting project. Would Strava data be not sufficient for you?

Comment: Thanks for the Strava data source suggestion. Unfortunetely, they do not provide some publicly available trip data (with power meter measurements, coordinates and time). And I disagree that no answer can be useful to the community, as someone may share his/her trip powermeter data and someone else may use it later for similar to mine projects. However, I agree, that is ask for data and not direct question.

Comment: For sample data to test your system you could use any sample ride data (it's in xml format despite what the file extension may say) and add your own sample power data.
You could also try getting in contact with the owner of http://bikecalculator.com/index.html and see if he will share his calculations, as that site is widely accepted to produce accurate estimates

Comment: I suggest rewording the question so it isn't closed for being off-topic. Rather than fishing for file, you may ask for analyzes or ranges of power by duration.  See the [community guidelines](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think you are trying to make mywindsock.com

Comment: Yes, my project has similar goals with mywindsock. Basically, I am trying to understand how good some physical model can approximate power output, given a weather conditions and  individual cycling parameters (total mass, aerodynamic drag coefficient, rolling resistance coefficient). For that I need sample of riding data (long enough, as I can observe weather only every hour in any location, containing rider power input). Using one ride I can estimate individual cycle parameters of the model. Using another ride I can evaluate model and see how good it approximates reality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it's a request for collaboration, not a question.

Comment: This looks like an interesting project but we're a question and answer site, not a notice board for wanted ads. Unfortunately, your post is outside the remit of the whole network, because it's not a question.

Comment: I think its a great idea, but its not a good fit for the Q&A format.  Strava might be your best source, but licence/reuse permission might be difficult.  Or try and find local cyclists who own a real power meter (look for the thunderflash icon in strava otherwise they're estimates.)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a power file (although I am happy to provide some examples), what you do need to do your calculations are the [power curves](https://www.cyclinganalytics.com/blog/2012/06/watts-kg-on-the-power-curve) and total weight so you can calculate watts/kg.

[image: example watts per kg power curve]

The ability of humans produce sustainable power changes over the duration. The highest power is produced for short intervals, with a rapid drop off from 1 sec to 1 min interval, followed by a leveling out over time.

Most online training analyzers will provide this.  [Strava](https://www.strava.com) actually provides these figures to members, and allows you to access power curves of riders you follow that upload power data.  You can also download files of athletes you follow (i.e., those who allow you to follow them).

Therefore you will need to:

1. Make an account on [Strava](https://www.strava.com)
2. Make friends with some users who have a power meter
3. Become a "follower" - it's kind of like joining a cult.
4. Download/analyze applicable rides.

To get you started below are a couple power curve examples, one from a commute and another from an actual pro athlete (which would probably not be very indicative of touring efforts).

### Example - MAMIL Commute

Here is an example an out-of-shape middle age man in lycra (MAMIL) riding to work:

[image: MAMIL Commute]

This was last week, riding a tempo pace but not killing it. I was putting a reasonable effort on the climbs which is why the 20 minute power is around 300 watts, but didn't want to work too hard so the 1 hour power falls off and the short duration power is relatively low.

### Example - Pro Athlete

This is a high end example of a pro athlete (triathlete) riding full out for an hour in a cyclo-cross (CX) race, a type of racing known for its intensity:

[image: Pro]

They are putting in big efforts out of the corners (2000 watts!!!! - #$%!) and are maxed out everywhere else.  Here the CP60 (critical power - 60 minutes; also known as Functional Power Threshold [FTP]) is around 370 watts!!! Impressive fitness to say the least.

If you look at 5 minute power, which is a good indicator of potential fitness, the pro athlete is still putting out almost 100 watts more power than the MAMIL commuter example.  That is 30% more capability! Granted I wasn't completely maxed out on my commute, but there is no way I could find another 100 watts to match, plus I have more weight which would put me at a lower watts/kg and a further disadvantage.

### Summary

Both examples are probably outside what someone on a long cycle trip will want to do.  I would simply shift the curves down appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! In fact I do need data  table I have described to do my calculations (i.e. timestamp, location, altitude, power measurement). Using this table I can estimate parameters of my physical model that approximate reality. Using another table with another ride but same rider and same bike I can evaluate how good the model actually is.

Comment: I have tried to download such raw data from strava, but either it is impossible, or I just cannot find the right button. Strava only provides graphs and plots based on the raw data I need. I would be happy and grateful, if you could share such tables with me.

Comment: @a.grochmal you could also contact Strava , as I think they can / are willing / won't completely shut off give data to developers. There's a way for sure to suck the data from users that allow you to do so if you are a third party app, like stravistix or stratistic do. Check Strava labs page, which is independent from Strava itself